# Needed proxy settings commands to install cocoapods on OS X. Also when I am trying to ping rubygems.org I get "Request timeout for icmp_seq" as result

Tags: ruby, macos, proxy, rubygems, cocoapods

$ sudo gem install cocoapods

ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'cocoapods' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide the code you have tried. Without it, error messages are rather useless.

Comment: @YakovL sudo gem install cocoapods. Thanks